# rasa-core Map entities to other entites

Tags: rasa-core

I am building a simple food ordering bot. In this I have a take_order intent in which two entities will be extracted food_item and quantity, both of these entities have list types in slots, for example if a user message like this comes:

I would like to have [one] (quantity) [chicken burger] (food_item) and [two] (quantity) [fries] (food_item)

slot for this example will be: slot{“quantity”: [“one”, “two”], “food_item”: [“chicken burger”, “fries”]}

in the action user_take_order I will be multiplying quantity of each item to its price and giving total bill to the user.

But I have a problem, in a complex case when user do not provide a quantity for the food_item, I will be assuming the default quantity to one but the problem occurs when user orders three items and do not provide quantity for only the second item, for example:

I would like to have [one] (quantity) [chicken burger] (food_item), [fries] (food_item) and [two] (quantity) [soft drinks] (food_item)

in this example no quantity is provided for the fries and slots filled: slot{“quantity”: [“one”, “two”], “food_item”: [“chicken burger”, “fries”, “cold drink”]}

in the action user_take_order I would like to do this:

```
1 x price_of_chicken_burger
1 x price_of_fries
2 x price_of_cold_drink
```

but the problem is that in quantity slot I have only quantities of chicken burger and cold drink and I do not have a clue that user did not mention the quantity of fries( I want to set quantity of fries as 1 “default case”)

have I choose the wrong types for slots quantity and food_item?

```
slots:
  food_item:
    type: list
  quantity:
    type: list
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to extract quantity and food item as one entity:

I would like to have [one chicken burger] (quantity_food_item), [fries] (quantity_food_item) and [two soft drinks] (quantity_food_item)

then differentiate them inside an action.